# How to highlight the subdivision's outline programmatically in a GeoJson layer?

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

There is a GeoJson sourced layer in my map,and subdivision's outline will be highlighted when mouse overring it due to corresponded event registered.
     Question is how to highlight a subdivision's outline programmatically(not by mouse overring)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find programmatically the feature (subdivision's outline) that you want highlight.

I suppose you have already defined a source, vector layer and overlay (it is a layer that contains only the features which are highlighted) in your code:

```
source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '[your url]',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    ...........

layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source
    .....................

overlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
     .........................
```

First it is necessary to find all the features

```
var _features = source.getFeatures();
```

Then you need a name or id to find the feature:

```
for (i = 0; i < _features.length; i++) {
            if (_features[i].get('name') === name) {
                _feature = _features[i];
                break;
            }
        }
```

The you will add the feature to the overlay vector layer:

```
overlay.getSource().addFeature(_feature);
```